# C++ Read only random lines in a file

Tags: c++, c++11, c++builder

I had requirement to read text file but its too large then I decide to only read some lines in this file. Can I use seek method for jump given line? Then I can only read that line because that text file is too large reading whole file is wasting lot of time. If its not possible, any one give better solution for that? (seek to given line and read it) (I know binary text files are reading byte by byte)

ex of my file

```
event1 0

subevent 1

subevent 2

event2  3
```

(In my file after one event its display number of lines I want to seek for previous event)

Comment: you can't seek to a new line per say, this concept does not exist. You have to find where the line ends manually. The only way you can implement a "line" concept is if you had fixed lengths for each line, else you have to get line by line and skip the ones you don't want.

Comment: ...or by adding line numbers to the file.

Comment: @hansmaad: great idea - would work well, though if you randomly choose a line number then have to do binary or interpolated seeks to find it, it's still pretty expensive compared to direct indexing to a random location unrelated to line numbers then seeking the previous or next line ending....

Comment: @hansmaad, how does that help you seek to a particular "line"?

Comment: Is it really that large? Reading even a million line file on a modern machine is not that expensive.

Comment: @Nim You could do a binary search in the file.

Comment: @uberwulu: The problem is that the file is large and slow to parse; how will making it larger and slower to parse help?

Comment: Is reformatting the file to some format with fixed line lengths possible?

Comment: "I had requirement to read text file but its too large then I decide to only read some lines in this file" what exactly is it you are trying to achieve with the file? Maybe there is other ways to get at the info that you are seeking if you tell us more about the problem and less about how you are going to workaround it.

Comment: If you can change the file format, then the "obvious" thing to try is to make all lines the same length. Of course, this requires there to be an upper limit on a line, and if the upper limit is much larger than the average then you hugely bloat the file. So depending on your data it might not help.

Comment: @TonyD We did this where I previously worked.  Not with line numbers, but with the timestamp on lines in a log file (with a size in the Terabyte range), using binary search.  The command was invoked from the command line, and never took a noticeable time to finish.  It's obviously slower than a direct access, but it's not that bad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can seek to a point in the file then read from there.  One possible problem is that if the lines are all different lengths, a random location in the file will have a higher probability of being in a longer line: you're not getting evenly distributed probabilities of different lines.  If you really really must have identical probabilities then you need to make at least one pass over the file to find the start of each line - then you can store those offsets in a vector and randomly select a vector element to guide seeking to the line data in the file.  If you only care a little bit, then you can perhaps advance a small but random number of lines past the one you initially seek to... that will even the odds a bit, avoids the initial pass, but isn't perfect.  hansmaad's comment adds a neat approach too - perfect results with pretty-good performance - but requires that you have all the lines numbered in the file itself.

Comment: "You can seek to a point in the file then read from there": not if the file was opened in text mode.  Seeking to an arbitrary point is undefined behavior.  (It generally works under Unix, and will put you somewhere near under Windows, but it might do something totally random.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: interesting point - good to use binary mode then.  Cheers.

Comment: @JamesKanze: doesn't Posix define that text and binary mode are identical? Which if true would account for it generally working under Unix ;-) I don't remember the reference though, so it's possible that they're guaranteed identical in terms of the data you see but not in terms of seeking.

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm not sure how far it is guaranteed, but in practice, I think you can count on them being identical under Unix and Unix-like systems.  (The distinction between text and binary was introduced into C in order to support non-Unix systems.  It wasn't present before C started being used on non-Unix systems.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless each line has exactly the same length, you're going to have to scan through it.

If you want to jump around in it, you can scan through it, saving the offset of each line in a container of your choice, and then use that to seek to a specific line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the lines are variable / random length, I don't believe there is any built-in way to jump directly to the start of a particular line.  You can seek to an arbitrary *byte position* in the file.  However, this might land anywhere in the beginning / middle / end of a line.

My best suggestion would be to attack the problem in two steps:

First, make a complete pass through the file, byte by byte, searching for the start of each line.  Record the byte position of each line and store it into an array, vector, etc.  (Basically, you are creating an index that maps from line number to starting position.)  Then, when you have this index built up, you can easily jump to a particular line, by looking up the position in your index.

Comment: Thanks all of your answers actually your second idea is working currently in my mind also but  this file created by engine if after created, i want to do that task quickly problem is it get large time but i also think their are no other way to do that :( when considering this situation time is very important because time make some important decisions :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no built-in way to seek to a new line without already knowing where the lines are.  I can't tell you the *best way* to achieve your goal, because most of your question details *how* you're trying to accomplish it, not *what* it is you're actually trying to accomplish.  Therefore, I might go one of two ways with this:

1)  If you actually need every last bit of data from the file (there is no metadata or other information that can be discarded):

Someone mentioned scanning through the file, tracking the lines as you go and building an index with it so you can read in one line at a time.  This might work, and it would be the way to go if you actually need each line in its entirety, or if you only need the line number and plan on reading in small pieces at a time from there.  However, without knowing details about your constraints or requirements, I would not recommend reading in entire lines using this method for one main reason: I have no way of knowing that one line will not itself be too large to load (what if there is only one line in the file?).

Instead, I would simply allocate a buffer of a size that is an appropriate amount to process at a time, and process the file in chunks of that size until you reach the end.  You can stream more data in as you go.  Without additional details, I can't tell you what that magic number should be, but the size of the largest chunk of information you might need to process is a good starting point as a minimum.

2)  If you don't need every last bit of data from the file (you can discard some of the information in it), then you only need some of it.  If you only need select pieces of data, then they are easier to find if they are tagged (which is what XML is for).  There are lots of free XML parsers, or you can write your own.  Then you'd search for tags instead of arbitrary line numbers, and changes to the file that result in the data being in a different location won't affect your ability to find it if it's tagged, as it would if you're just going by line numbers.